# Update and verify phone number for firebase 2 factor authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have successfully built a web app using firebase 2-factor authentication. But There is a case that I am struggling to deal with:

that is the case when users want to update their phone number, we have to make sure that the number is correct before it is updated. We need to verify the number first then use the verification sent to the phone to do the updating. The code is below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";
import { fbAuth } from "@/services/firebase.service";

export function useRecaptcha(componentId) {
  const [recaptcha, setRecaptcha] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(componentId, {
      "size": "invisible",
      "callback": () => { },
      "expired-callback": () => {
        console.log("expired-callback");
      }
    }, fbAuth);

    setRecaptcha(recaptchaVerifier);

    return () => {
      recaptchaVerifier.clear();
    }
  }, [componentId]);

  return recaptcha;
}


import { useAuthContext } from "@/contexts/authContext"; import { useRecaptcha } from "@/hooks/useRecaptcha"; import withAuth from "@/hooks/withAuth";

import {   Box,   Button,   Input,   useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react"; import { PhoneAuthProvider, multiFactor } from "firebase/auth"; import { useState } from "react";

const mfaComponentId = "update_phone_number";

function HomePage() {   const { user, setIsLoading } = useAuthContext();

  const recaptcha = useRecaptcha(mfaComponentId);   const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState("");   const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState("");   const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("")

   async function verifyPhoneNumber(user, phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier) {
    const session = await multiFactor(user).getSession();
    const phoneInfoOptions = {
      phoneNumber,
      session
    }
  
    const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(fbAuth);
    try {
      return await phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recaptchaVerifier)
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    }   }

  return <>
    <Box>Change phone number</Box>
    <Box>
      <Input
        mx="4"
        w="80"
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChange={e => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
      <Button
        onClick={async () => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          try {
            const result = await verifyPhoneNumber(user, phoneNumber, recaptcha);
            setVerificationId(result);
          } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message)
          }
          setIsLoading(false);
        }}>Change phone number</Button>
      <Input
        mx="4"
        w="80"
        value={verificationCode}
        onChange={e => setVerificationCode(e.target.value)} />
      <Button
        onClick={async () => {
          const cred = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
          await updatePhoneNumber(user, cred)
        }}>Confirm change phone number</Button>
    </Box>
    <div id={mfaComponentId}></div>   </> }

export default withAuth(HomePage);
```

When execute the code, it requires the recent login. What is wrong here?